# NSWindow attached to cursor

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nscursor

I would like to make a custom panel, that shows a zoom at the current cursor-location.
Like for example 'Sip' does.
I have searched the web for examples, but didn't find anything specific.

I found `NSEvent`'s `addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:` and `addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:` methods.
Now I could just set the frame origin of the window.
But I'm not sure if that's really the right solution.

Is there a better way to do this?
Could anyone point me into some sample-code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's basically it.

You can also use the Quartz Event Tap function family CGEventTap, as it will provide a little more responsiveness during events like the Mac application switcher and Exposé or Mission Control or Dashboard. However, it is a little harder to set up, and uses a C callback approach that is a little tougher to use with some things.

Quartz Event Taps are otherwise the same thing, but possibly slightly faster.

If you use that, be sure to use the function `CGPoint CGEventGetUnflippedLocation(CGEventRef aCGEvent)`

As in:
 `CGPoint eventLocation = CGEventGetUnflippedLocation(aCGEvent);`

That will make sure your y coordinates are bottom left like the rest of Cocoa.
Otherwise use its sibling `CGEventGetLocation()` which for some odd reason of crappy naming doesn't indicate that it returns flipped coordinates. (but the docs do state this)